# Installing CartoDB on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cartodb

#### Purpose

I would like to install CartoDB on AWS EC2 and use it.
I want to eliminate an error occurring at login.

#### Details of the problem

We installed CartoDB on EC2 referring to the following website.
http://michaelminn.net/tutorials/carto-aws/

Go to `http://${EC2_PublicIP}:3000/`, enter the user and password set during the installation process and login
The following message was displayed, which made it impossible to operate after that.

```
Missing template public/static/dashboard/index.html with {:locale=>[:en], 
:formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]}. 
Searched in: 
* "/home/ubuntu/cartodb/app/views" 
* "/home/ubuntu/cartodb/gears/carto_gears_api/app/views" 
* "/home/ubuntu/cartodb" * "/"

Extracted source (around line #54):           
  def index
    render(file: "public/static/dashboard/index.html", layout: false)
  end
  def show

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/cartodb

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/admin/visualizations_controller.rb:54:in `index'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:150:in `wrap_in_profiler'
```

Sorry to trouble you, but please tell me how to fix the error.

#### Configuration

EC2 instance type: t2.medium
AMI ID: ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20180912 (ami-06c43a7df16e8213c)
Security group (inbound): 8080, 8181, 3000 are all open from 0.0.0.0/0

#### Web site you referred to

`http://michaelminn.net/tutorials/carto-aws/`
`https://cartodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html`
`https://blog.mylab.jp/posts/2016041101/`
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyIoeOB4x4g`

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I install the cartoDB in 2021 at aws? I am trying to contact you for help, its super urgent for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced the same problem.

First of all, check your SQL API Configuration, Map API Configuration, CARTO Builder Configuration for private and public aws ip's - this can be tricky, so you have to be very considerate.

Also, I succeeded with running

```
npm run build:static
export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin
bundle exec grunt --environment=development
```

inside cartodb directory just after

```
npm run carto-node
```

these steps are mentioned in official CartoDB docs as optional, but in my case all of the above made the thing.

Comment: I am trying to install CartoDB on aws currently on 2021, but failing with it. Can you provide any resource for it?